# Pentaho. Put error message from logging into string/field

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm wondering if there is some steps/solution for handling with the errors message and put them into some string or field in Pentaho tool?
For example if some error occur with connect into database then put that message from logging into string/field.

Comment: I know of no way to do this, but I'd sure like to know if there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use this in a `Evaluating JavaScript` step in a job, to get the error message, and handle it:

```
var logText = previous_result.getLogText();
parent_job.setVariable("LOG_TEXT", logText);

true;
```

Comment: If somewhere list of predefined variables available in JavaScrip step like "previous_result", "parent_job"?

Comment: @bolav, do you know of any source with such useful variables?